# Ajax response which sets javascript variable covers up any html elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, response

is there anyway to do this? My ajax sets a javascript variable but when i try to display it, using document.write, it covers the html elements. Can this be done so that i can use the javascript variables and not cover up the html elements? Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Log In</title>

<!-- script tag for ajax jquery -->
<link href='style.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function()

              {
              //Get Data ajax function 
              $.post(
                     'getData.php',
                     {

                     },                                           
                     function(response)
                     {
                     $('#name').html($('#1' , response).html());
                     $('#sname').html($('#2' , response).html()); 

                     var x = $('#1' , response).html();
                     document.write(x);

                     })

              return false;
              })

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="name"></div>
<div id="sname"></div>

this is text that get covered up, as well as any other html elements 


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the first place, why are you using document.write() and in the second place why are you trying to write it in the <head>? When jQuery runs its `ready` method the page is already loaded and the HTML stream is closed.

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` is primarily for use *during* the loading of the page. When responding to events, you modify the DOM via functions like `createElement`, `appendChild`, and the like; or properties like `innerHTML`.

For instance, if you wanted to append the content of your `x` as markup within a `div`, instead of

```
document.write(x);
```

you'd do this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = x;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

If you wanted to *find* an element already in the DOM and modify it, you could do that with `document.getElementById` if it has an ID, or `document.getElementsByTagName` to get a list of elements with a given tag (both part of [DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)), or (on most but not all current browsers), `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` from the [selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/).

More reading:

- [DOM2 Core spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/#auto-toc-6)
- [Selectors API Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/)

Answer (score 2):

So since you are using jQuery, you shouldn't be using document.write because of the reasons other people have highlighted.  Use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function()

          {
          //Get Data ajax function 
          $.post(
                 'getData.php',
                 {

                 },                                           
                 function(response)
                 {
                 $('#name').html($('#1' , response).html());
                 $('#sname').html($('#2' , response).html()); 

                 var x = $('#1' , response).html();
                 // Use .append() instead of document.write()
                 $('body').append(x);
                 })

          return false;
          })
```

That way you won't lose any existing data.